# Javascript как заставить работать со всеми блоками одного класса

Tags: javascript

Есть страница с блоками и скрипт, помогите доделать скрипт, что бы он работал со всеми загруженными блоками shop-info и с теми которые подгружаются после нажатия на кнопку "показать еще". На данный момент он работает только с первым блоком.

Это скрипт поиска-замены, по шаблону из list.txt, в листе задаются искомое и заменяемое слово через | , Получаем замену слов в блоке shop-info , например Педро|Петя

```
<div class="shop-info">Привет Работает только со мной</div>
<div class="shop-info">Привет</div>
<div class="shop-info">Привет</div>
<div class="shop-info">Привет</div>
<div class="shop-info">Привет</div>

<div id="shop-page-more"><button onclick="shopPageMore({more:shop_page+1})">Показать ещё...</button></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $.get('/list.txt', function (data) {
      var elem = document.querySelector('.shop-info'),
          content = elem.innerHTML,
          list = [];
      data.replace(/^(.*?)\|(.*?)$/gm, function (a, b, c) {
        content = content.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\s|\\b)(' + b.replace(/[\\\/()*+.?|]/g, '\\$1') + ')(\\.|\\s|\\b|&|$)', 'igm'), '$1' + c + '$3');
      });
      elem.innerHTML = content;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Странно видеть вместе jQuery и `document.querySelector`. Для выбора всех элементов с классом `shop-info` нужно использовать `$(".shop-info")`, или `document.querySelectorAll(".shop-info")`, или `document.getElementsByClassName("shop-info")`. Как это соединить со смесью из `$.get` и двух `replace`-ов - это надо разбираться в коде.

Comment: Вот, например, отсутствие присваивания результата `data.replace` куда-либо, равно как и отсутствие `return`-а в функции, передаваемой вторым параметром в `replace`, намекает на то, что тут предполагается использование вовсе не `replace`-a.

Comment: @Regent, там просто split по строкам, и разбиение строки по символу `|`.

Comment: @Grundy а где в `data.replace` разбиение по строкам? Я не особо стал вчитываться в регулярные выражения (особенно в которое `new RegExp`). В общем и целом это выглядит как решение какой-то задачи сложным, малопонятным образом.

Comment: @Regent, `/^(.*?)\|(.*?)$/gm` - здесь стоит флаг `m` - `multiline`, в этом случае символы `^` и `$` значат не только начало и конец файла, но и начало и конец строки. Далее в этой строке выделяется текст с начала строки до символа `|` и текст после это символа до конца строки.

Comment: а какое содержимое `list.txt`

Answer (score 1):

сделал бы так:

```
var elem = $('.shop-info');
elem.html(function(index, content)
  /*действия*/ 
  return content;
});
```

Comment: если уж использовать jQuery то вместо innerHTML стоило использовать `html` метод, да и цикл прямой не нужен

Comment: @Grundy как тогда без такого цикла?

Comment: [.html( function )](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function)

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, исправил.

Comment: `$(this).html();` не нужен. Текущий _content_ приходит вторым параметром. Так что можно заменить на `elem.html(function(index, content){ `. Плюс, в конце, просто вернуть полученную строку вместо `$(this).html(content);`

Comment: осталось только немного развернуть ответ

Comment: Эта скрипт поиска-замены, по шаблону из list.txt, в листе задаются искомое и заменяемое слово через   | , Получаем замену слов в блоке shop-info , например Педро|Петя

Comment: @Евгений, а ты посмотрел, что написано в ответе, и что написано у тебя в коде?

Comment: $(function () {
    $.get('/list.txt', function (data) {
      var elem = $('.shop-info');
elem.html(function(index, content){
          list = [];
      data.replace(/^(.*?)\|(.*?)$/gm, function (a, b, c) {
        content = content.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\s|\\b)(' + b.replace(/[\\\/()*+.?|]/g, '\\$1') + ')(\\.|\\s|\\b|&|$)', 'igm'), '$1' + c + '$3');
return content;
      });
    });
});
});

Comment: У меня только поверхностные знания о скриптах, я не могу понять как это все связать